# symbolication with atos giving wrong reason for the crash

Tags: crash-reports

In my current project I am getting random crashes,may be due to memory overshoot.But I actually want to figure out which class lead to that crash.So I used symbolication method to find the reason of crash. 
Here is what I have done:

Firstly, XCode Build settings are like this :

Strip Debug Sysbols During Copy : NO
Deployment PostProcessing : YES
Strip Linked Product : YES
Generate Debug Symbols : YES
Debug Info Format : DWARF with dSYM file
Use Separate Strip : YES

I am using iOS 5.1 with 4.3.2 version of XCode. I have used "symbolicatecrash" and "atos" methods to reveal the reason of the crash.But I was not able to find the reason for the crash.

So I tried this. I made the application crash by myself by accessing an out of bound index from the array. I have used that to verify the symbolicated crash result output with my actual crash.

Here is the crash report output:

```
Incident Identifier: 93678EE5-ED10-4502-A59B-5C7526640C4D
CrashReporter Key:   5a79e41767bd1988a9b4080ee5641f63ed42feb8
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         MyAppName [887]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/EF2C944B-4C26-4EB6-B41E-F89CF2232ADB/JAYPORE.app/MyAppName
Identifier:      MyAppName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-13 13:37:18.642 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3028432c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37725f54 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3771efe4 abort + 88
3   MyAppName                           0x00104aa0 0x5e000 + 682656
4   Foundation                      0x34ebc1b0 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 260
5   Foundation                      0x34ebbe42 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 130
6   MyAppName                           0x00104924 0x5e000 + 682276
7   MyAppName                           0x00118634 0x5e000 + 763444
8   MyAppName                           0x00116b36 0x5e000 + 756534
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37730532 _sigtramp + 42
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x37725f54 pthread_kill + 48
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3771efe4 abort + 88
12  MyAppName                           0x00118658 0x5e000 + 763480
13  CoreFoundation                  0x37c23980 __handleUncaughtException + 68
14  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3776f2ca _objc_terminate + 122
15  libc++abi.dylib                 0x3017e3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
16  libc++abi.dylib                 0x3017e44a std::terminate() + 14
17  libc++abi.dylib                 0x3017f81e __cxa_rethrow + 82
18  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3776f22e objc_exception_rethrow + 6
19  CoreFoundation                  0x37b7953e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
20  CoreFoundation                  0x37b7939e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
21  GraphicsServices                0x37950fc6 GSEventRunModal + 150
22  UIKit                           0x316f973c UIApplicationMain + 1084
23  MyAppName                           0x0005ffc8 0x5e000 + 8136
24  MyAppName                           0x0005ff6c 0x5e000 + 8044

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x302743b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x307dff74 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x307dfc92 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30274010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30274206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37bf741c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37bf6154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37b794d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37b7939e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x32650128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7c16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30274010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30274206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37bf741c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37bf6154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37b794d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37b7939e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x34ec8bc2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x34ec8a8a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x34f5c59a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7c16 _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30284570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x37bfb66a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7c16 _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFURLCACHE_work_queue
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30275ac4 fsync + 8
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x30741656 0x30704000 + 251478
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x30746434 0x30704000 + 271412
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x30741394 0x30704000 + 250772
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x30737350 0x30704000 + 209744
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x30719a6c 0x30704000 + 88684
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3072ccb4 0x30704000 + 167092
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3072b6ce sqlite3_step + 2098
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3070a732 sqlite3_exec + 366
9   CFNetwork                       0x33a3cedc __CFURLCache::ExecSQLStatement_NoLock(sqlite3*, char const*, int (*)(void*, int, char**, char**), void*, long) + 32
10  CFNetwork                       0x33a3fc7c _ZL24_CFURLCacheTimerCallbackPv + 320
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x307e133e _dispatch_source_invoke + 510
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x307dec60 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 44
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x307ded9e _dispatch_queue_drain + 198
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x307dec56 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 34
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x307df860 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 204
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e21c8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e209c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30284cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e230a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e209c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30284cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e230a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e209c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30274010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30274206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x37bf741c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x37bf6154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x37b794d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x37b7939e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x34ebcb7e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x34ed652c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 72
8   JAYPORE                         0x00108a9a 0x5e000 + 699034
9   Foundation                      0x34ec8a8a -[NSThread main] + 66
10  Foundation                      0x34f5c59a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7c16 _pthread_start + 314
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e7ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30284cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e230a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e209c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30284cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e230a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e209c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30284cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e230a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x376e209c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3f504ce8      r6: 0x30caec02      r7: 0x2fe5c4ec
    r8: 0x00000006    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000005     r11: 0x2fe5c558
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe5c4e0      lr: 0x37725f5b      pc: 0x3028432c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x5e000 -   0x14efff +JAYPORE armv7  <a9b02230373d3b4aba282d21f94fb780> /var/mobile/Applications/EF2C944B-4C26-4EB6-B41E-F89CF2232ADB/JAYPORE.app/JAYPORE
 0x1178000 -  0x1182fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <45d7c264810c364b976dba254572d73d> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe5d000 - 0x2fe7efff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3001c000 - 0x30179fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
```

...long list of binary images.

Now when I use "atos" to get the reason of crash from the Thread 0(which caused the crash)

```
3   MyAppName                           0x00104aa0 0x5e000 + 682656
```

using above address,it gives me this output:

```
MAC66:Resources sourabhbhardwaj$ atos -arch arm -o /Users/myPath/MyAppName.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyAppName 0x00079f6c 0x78000 + 8044
-[FirstViewController setUIAndText] (in MyAppName) (FirstViewController.m:85)
-[SecondViewController DeleteByID:] (in MyAppName) (SecondViewController.m:415)
+
-[MyController viewWillAppear:] (in MyAppName) (MyController.m:137)
```

which is not the actual line of crash which I have made. I have made crash on other view controller and the output is entirely different.How can this be possible??
Yes,I have cross checked that I am using the exact same dSYM file for that binary.

Quick help needed.

Thanks
Sourabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before symbolicating, make sure you have the same `.app` and the `.dSYM` of the build that crashed or else it will not be symbolicated properly.

Comment: I have used the same .app and .dSYM file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is too late to help, but just in case: you may not be giving atos all the parameters it needs.  In particular, make sure you are specifying (with -l) the load address of the application, and (with -arch) the architecture.  You can find this in the binary image line you quoted above (it changes with each crashdump):

```
0x5e000 -   0x14efff +JAYPORE armv7  <a9b02230373d3b4aba282d21f94fb780> /var/mobile/Applications/EF2C944B-4C26-4EB6-B41E-F89CF2232ADB/JAYPORE.app/JAYPORE
```

The 0x5e000 is the load address.  So try running something like `xcrun atos -l 0x5e000 -arch armv7 -o YourArchive.xcarchive/Products/Applications/YourApp.app/YourApp 0x00104aa0`.

You can find more details about what the load address is and why it changes each time in [Kerni's answer to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576028/225176).  (But while it's good to know how it works, it's usually more convenient to use the -l parameter to atos rather than doing the math yourself.)