# iPhone dSYM Crash Log Symbols

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports

My app crashes on iPhones and not the simulator. I got the crash log from my device (which does not include the named symbols).

I found the dSYM file in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archive/YYYY-MM-DD/AppName.xcarchive/dSYMs/AppName.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/AppName`

I ran: `atos -arch armv7 -o AppName 0x33c2f838` (the hash on thread 0 after `libsystem_kernel.dylib`. `atos` outputs back the hash to me without any symbol name.

What is wrong with what I'm doing? Why is `atos` returning back the hash? How can I get the symbol names?

The crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: F415FF30-D0F9-4E53-997E-622CF775E141
CrashReporter Key:   fa0a3164a061d78d15ee4f1187d40172474ef57f
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         TipnTag [3170]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/1F6166EF-6048-4EBD-895E-B2873079C906/TipnTag.app/TipnTag
Identifier:      TipnTag
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-01-12 16:14:35.916 +0300
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3bf3a29e 0x35e2997a 0x3bf3a1c0 0x3520948c 0x352111d2 0xbb986 0xbbacc 0x8bfa0 0x350b7540 0x3509c306 0x350b37c2 0x3506f7fe 0x38943d5e 0x389438fc 0x38944830 0x38944216 0x38944024 0x38943e84 0x3bf0f6c8 0x3bf0d9bc 0x3bf0dd12 0x3be80eb8 0x3be80d44 0x3a24e2e6 0x350c02f4 0x79248 0x791e4)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c2f838 0x33c1f000 + 67640
1   TipnTag                         0x0010166e 0x78000 + 562798
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf3a57c 0x3be78000 + 796028
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35e29a62 0x35e21000 + 35426
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a119078 0x3a118000 + 4216
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a119110 0x3a118000 + 4368
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3a11a594 0x3a118000 + 9620
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x35e299cc 0x35e21000 + 35276
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80f1c 0x3be78000 + 36636
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80d44 0x3be78000 + 36164
10  GraphicsServices                0x3a24e2e6 0x3a249000 + 21222
11  UIKit                           0x350c02f4 0x35069000 + 357108
12  TipnTag                         0x00079248 0x78000 + 4680
13  TipnTag                         0x000791e4 0x78000 + 4580

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c30d98 0x33c1f000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96cf6 0x36f90000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96a12 0x36f90000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f968a0 0x36f90000 + 26784

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c20648 0x33c1f000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a233974 0x3a22b000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a233654 0x3a22b000 + 34388

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c30d98 0x33c1f000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96cf6 0x36f90000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96a12 0x36f90000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f968a0 0x36f90000 + 26784

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c1feb4 0x33c1f000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c20048 0x33c1f000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0f040 0x3be78000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0dd9e 0x3be78000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80eb8 0x3be78000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80d44 0x3be78000 + 36164
6   WebCore                         0x37b5fa40 0x37b55000 + 43584
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa130e 0x36f90000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa11d4 0x36f90000 + 70100

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c1feb4 0x33c1f000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c20048 0x33c1f000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0f040 0x3be78000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0dd9e 0x3be78000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80eb8 0x3be78000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80d44 0x3be78000 + 36164
6   Foundation                      0x36cbabc8 0x36c8d000 + 187336
7   Foundation                      0x36d3e678 0x36c8d000 + 726648
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa130e 0x36f90000 + 70414
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa11d4 0x36f90000 + 70100

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c30d98 0x33c1f000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96cf6 0x36f90000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96a12 0x36f90000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f968a0 0x36f90000 + 26784

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c1feb4 0x33c1f000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c20048 0x33c1f000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0f040 0x3be78000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0dd9e 0x3be78000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80eb8 0x3be78000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80d44 0x3be78000 + 36164
6   Foundation                      0x36c9178a 0x36c8d000 + 18314
7   Foundation                      0x36d35058 0x36c8d000 + 688216
8   TipnTag                         0x00116b10 0x78000 + 650000
9   Foundation                      0x36d3e678 0x36c8d000 + 726648
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa130e 0x36f90000 + 70414
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa11d4 0x36f90000 + 70100

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c30d98 0x33c1f000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96cf6 0x36f90000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96a12 0x36f90000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f968a0 0x36f90000 + 26784

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c1feb4 0x33c1f000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c20048 0x33c1f000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0f040 0x3be78000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf0dd9e 0x3be78000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80eb8 0x3be78000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3be80d44 0x3be78000 + 36164
6   Foundation                      0x36c9178a 0x36c8d000 + 18314
7   Foundation                      0x36d35058 0x36c8d000 + 688216
8   TipnTag                         0x000cf77c 0x78000 + 358268
9   Foundation                      0x36d3e678 0x36c8d000 + 726648
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa130e 0x36f90000 + 70414
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa11d4 0x36f90000 + 70100

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c30d98 0x33c1f000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96cf6 0x36f90000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f96a12 0x36f90000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36f968a0 0x36f90000 + 26784

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x33c30594 0x33c1f000 + 71060
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3bf131f2 0x3be78000 + 635378
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa130e 0x36f90000 + 70414
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36fa11d4 0x36f90000 + 70100

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3c930fc8
    r4: 0xffffffff    r5: 0x0000000b      r6: 0x2fd88304      r7: 0x2fd889e0
    r8: 0x2fd88310    r9: 0x3cf0e8a8     r10: 0x2fd88554     r11: 0x0000000b
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fd882e0      lr: 0x00101673      pc: 0x33c2f838
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x78000 -   0x1a6fff +TipnTag armv7  <7bc47846a23f32fe8a5781dd61fdbbf5> /var/mobile/Applications/1F6166EF-6048-4EBD-895E-B2873079C906/TipnTag.app/TipnTag
0x2feed000 - 0x2ff0dfff  dyld armv7  <75594988728831d98e1f7c4c7b7ca29d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x33551000 - 0x33556fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <3a351ca1d4ae3146a787f3e13564294b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3362e000 - 0x33633fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <021ff140d6003f3281dfa29b79fa9e6e> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x337b8000 - 0x337c4fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <a3bba3842596315a81aa171a8bbda7b5> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x338af000 - 0x338eafff  AppSupport armv7  <74ed50d2f7d23ce696b029dd817749c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x338eb000 - 0x33950fff  CoreMedia armv7  <28a1fe1e729d37e0bb623201b2652a45> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33c1f000 - 0x33c35fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <4c2862d2e8f23119bfe114b0662c6241> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x33ea8000 - 0x33ea8fff  vecLib armv7  <66204595f7653ef29e5e26cb8629177a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x33f32000 - 0x33f43fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <a3d025234d1a3880a0e5f87879633ee0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x33f8f000 - 0x34167fff  ImageIO armv7  <fdfa8aa6307235b29435e5c8f6bc9819> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x34224000 - 0x3429afff  MapKit armv7  <e4016aefbae43bd886ed6e6e5375ba47> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x342e8000 - 0x34420fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903960bfcfe93adb943752851f88491e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x345f6000 - 0x345fdfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <257ecb171a363e4298a63f72d7fffea2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3461c000 - 0x34623fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <6e39f8511ecc3c3489829714eb6fde12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x34626000 - 0x346c6fff  UIFoundation armv7  <795a2f216cc3379c95eb645c633cc527> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x346e1000 - 0x34720fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <44d84d23d10f344c90b4d9e9611ec976> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x34721000 - 0x34745fff  Bom armv7  <c76b4156e0463ecb922608d44c126d86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34748000 - 0x34748fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <f2cad3bd15f63f448a9c5be732c65819> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3481b000 - 0x34858fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <7db25f3d55b93f31868e37326fba1e57> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x34f83000 - 0x35008fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <759ca29f533a33e88a81fddc3364bf19> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35069000 - 0x355bcfff  UIKit armv7  <4f85b22a1eb73af08641066b29c4edb2> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x355bd000 - 0x35631fff  ProofReader armv7  <cc89a352199a393ba0e46af69e670ef9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35697000 - 0x35784fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <faa5abb937e3306ab87c7f7c38315839> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3591f000 - 0x35934fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <9fbb123276823c2383fc34b7a55404d7> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x35935000 - 0x35973fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <250b8df69b3c3f929f30463d218b7462> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35974000 - 0x35976fff  OAuth armv7  <d3e2bc9ae64b31f0a89c52dc1c2797fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x35ba0000 - 0x35ba3fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <6edd9c74c5a73c33809152446abe1538> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x35db1000 - 0x35db2fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <46cd200d99323aebbf6d81e5fb16424f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x35e21000 - 0x35f1ffff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <5224e803eca737a4b2c6451d136b3d28> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x35fa0000 - 0x35facfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <e98708fbfa683df2a91d45dc765071a7> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x36233000 - 0x36295fff  CoreText armv7  <4a0bece315e9316fa1aa1b5923740f55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3629c000 - 0x362b3fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <a5570d37cd3f30cbb9572a9cdb824126> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x362eb000 - 0x363a0fff  CoreImage armv7  <ad658acd554a386fb81bb137a237b5f4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x363a1000 - 0x363b6fff  liblzma.5.dylib armv7  <2bfdc69b7f403270b2366e5e2448d520> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x36477000 - 0x36566fff  GeoServices armv7  <60e2738ccb9635e9874907d54ea27b68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x3658f000 - 0x365bdfff  Security armv7  <fb75984442a435cd84aac722142d5a44> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x365be000 - 0x365befff  Accelerate armv7  <22bee3e96cbc3538bfc50ca5be618cc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x36673000 - 0x36699fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <134c41c587fb33dca014bd525f68a0c7> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x36749000 - 0x36768fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <ed705f425035329d96ede473f023ed84> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x36769000 - 0x367befff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e5b7289acd1231acb950569a81c10ac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36835000 - 0x36838fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <2a9fe0b48f473d0f8fe2bf076cd12753> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x36863000 - 0x36b74fff  Altitude armv7  <6679eb99396833dfae5041e9a9667c8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Altitude.framework/Altitude
0x36b81000 - 0x36bdafff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <ad4c53081a263f0d96f63b9a80f2ae91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x36bdb000 - 0x36becfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <8b9821bc87ba354297392cb50da7be58> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x36c8d000 - 0x36e50fff  Foundation armv7  <2e1ac190c4f837e2a1059043dd7b1c63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x36e5e000 - 0x36eaafff  IMFoundation armv7  <fd1c50ba98f9307f8b06d074aed412b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36f90000 - 0x37016fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <d45dc8901531343caf9b7e703d3eba50> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x37a4f000 - 0x37a74fff  OpenCL armv7  <f7e2cb8404653022bf5cdea17bc5d06f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x37aac000 - 0x37ae7fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <bc5b8d4a10863ce192acf26428e68da7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x37b3f000 - 0x37b54fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <3afeeea531013420af75315d8d6dd332> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x37b55000 - 0x38484fff  WebCore armv7  <29cc251f63fe3a9eb16e96742b88ac4f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x384bb000 - 0x38514fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d831f1f9285535acac5035a29d84aaaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x38695000 - 0x38699fff  IOSurface armv7  <959e67366a553eca85e6ccfa2d668366> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x386ee000 - 0x386f1fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <df4096b1cdc5335790db9a2a51e6b029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x386f2000 - 0x386f5fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <e08b913e17753180b91728a8bd5dda7b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x38940000 - 0x38a55fff  QuartzCore armv7  <d96571a6986c3012b315cb860f4d65ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x38a56000 - 0x38a64fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <d0fb0eda6cb53a4da859d598c59e7522> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x38af2000 - 0x38b0dfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <51845c89677f3e77aeb221c44bda48f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x38b36000 - 0x38b3bfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <7bde3532f2953f3894eb725379575926> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x38cc0000 - 0x38cc9fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5258dce78afc3fd7934a5674b92ad785> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x38cd6000 - 0x38ce2fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <0338ce49444332ec88cfc45c624bb39b> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x38ce5000 - 0x38cebfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9e8bfe02e370375ea8439ab895528982> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x38d13000 - 0x38df6fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <56d8e00447133cd89457deec007327cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x38f2c000 - 0x38f32fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <690aaa493b5c3f9582499f174adf4964> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x38f33000 - 0x38f8bfff  CoreLocation armv7  <7bca9c29b3d23f61ba0e28af9e8ee357> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x38f8c000 - 0x38f93fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e035b741746c316dba8f1e59a568bf17> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x38fc1000 - 0x38fc3fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <7add7c91a2673641b0c5f0433a203da6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x390cf000 - 0x390ecfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd76b3fcb0db3922ad62f547ab2e55fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x39102000 - 0x39122fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <7f6f63b31f333c41952f685fdd54a6cb> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x39127000 - 0x3918bfff  AddressBook armv7  <bdf14ca2b4fb32e5bdb2a9fafb460f09> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3918c000 - 0x3918dfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <6a0dd04f0710329b9c1722db2235f5c3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3918e000 - 0x391d7fff  IOKit armv7  <635953fdb81237e991ab57ccff92e97d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x39203000 - 0x39204fff  DataMigration armv7  <25f8874067393208acc083124bc3eb86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3924f000 - 0x3924ffff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <1fd63e8305ab3ca190b1ef6ab2555f9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x39250000 - 0x39251fff  CoreSurface armv7  <aa216ca3e2e0381ea8cf9abbd6f430f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x39454000 - 0x39459fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <cb484bdaf5003e4baa13f83bafff62a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x394a2000 - 0x39648fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <8171afa18a08371c89cab6c9d823d1c5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x39660000 - 0x396abfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <55a7612b28c43cfcad7089b688591b80> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x396b2000 - 0x396b7fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <15aa2c3c8d523273913d4fc6717d3b7c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x396eb000 - 0x396ecfff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <3a149b4730663b1ea84e4a0a68ccc689> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x39775000 - 0x3977cfff  XPCObjects armv7  <5bc4f7282e9d3945a6c1885217670667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x39a01000 - 0x39ac6fff  CFNetwork armv7  <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x39b83000 - 0x39b99fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <9b3fd56781103f209be2c43e48c1efc9> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39d40000 - 0x39d40fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <8a2e3a8fdf9335e2867a33e2d1a9baf8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x39d7b000 - 0x39d93fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <be3d5625aed733ffb2d53400655fe110> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x39d94000 - 0x39d95fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <6c912cedc1e938ad914dfce91a529b68> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x39d9b000 - 0x39d9efff  MobileInstallation armv7  <e6b6ae9d4f5f3831a40fcc370afc1429> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x39dcd000 - 0x39ddafff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <19dbc34167323bca9510012b926d8cf7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x39e40000 - 0x39e96fff  CoreAudio armv7  <a3a2eb3a29443b42a23aa8ecb1232846> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x39ea9000 - 0x39ed1fff  PrintKit armv7  <a8ef6136b9773d42ac20f7eb54279039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x39f8b000 - 0x39f97fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <74d50f4c8d243a35ad3ae89d85f2793a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x39f98000 - 0x39fb1fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <e1f8d258d02c344cb0d17cec31818d3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x39fed000 - 0x39ff9fff  AccountSettings armv7  <0b7524e9a8ef36bf9e9f6a5c445478af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3a0cb000 - 0x3a0dcfff  Accounts armv7  <07b95faa96e73ffeb52694cbad7f3528> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x3a0e2000 - 0x3a117fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <ebd023957d853fa8bd35309592e92dac> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3a118000 - 0x3a12bfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <c5a5f03138353747b539e620ef2bb5c0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x3a189000 - 0x3a18bfff  TCC armv7  <f641dd0500fa3f0087d93da665ea84b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x3a18f000 - 0x3a1a4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3a22b000 - 0x3a248fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <4abccf75caf33fa5a0c6037b2e1c5f41> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3a249000 - 0x3a254fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <c5879083e8693aba827c78a32abe2391> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3a2b4000 - 0x3a2bcfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <359ccc7700c93d58adbbd74ecfda80d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3a2c9000 - 0x3a2e5fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <7b2a25c750063de480f6a691f716b9d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x3a2e6000 - 0x3a2f8fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <000fb77814ee3ca0841e14bbba48867d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3a322000 - 0x3a496fff  VectorKit armv7  <3b697bc4593d3e9596ae9f73ff75e5cb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit
0x3a560000 - 0x3a560fff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a04b639c18593885bd81bfa623a6f07c> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3a593000 - 0x3a59cfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e51cbfefefbc30b6b47d99739123033e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3a59d000 - 0x3a59dfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <993c9bfe8bf031548b9ddba63cc17015> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3a9ac000 - 0x3a9b2fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <a81d768a49cf37a1a111594d39cea3fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3a9c4000 - 0x3a9cafff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <6c1c1aaf9a3537d7ada4b519d14da7ab> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3b119000 - 0x3b171fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <fa250e174ca43d3c93a61e41f0df9771> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3b1d5000 - 0x3b1d9fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <6a8f59f89218372d9f24c4193a179008> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x3b202000 - 0x3b203fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <de8af6be681832008d180d7424d55f0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x3b214000 - 0x3b2c1fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <ef245c0afc113f54b6f30921671edab2> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x3b5ee000 - 0x3b638fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <a361a382693032b9bdfb2860033b3024> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3b9ee000 - 0x3bb2cfff  vImage armv7  <a7fd7fcd7041356db2ca297402ab6e8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3bb2d000 - 0x3bb3cfff  CoreVideo armv7  <092f3aa965803a1aaea69af2ac5143f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3bc6b000 - 0x3bdb4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <0253932c1b9038a0849ef73c38e076ca> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3be4b000 - 0x3be4dfff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <4fd03b13dbfe32628adc789367f48ce1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3be78000 - 0x3bfaafff  CoreFoundation armv7  <e30fc309df7b3c9f8ac57f0f6047d65f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3bfdb000 - 0x3c3eefff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <0cb7a12beb3d32c1abd1834be8328b7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3c409000 - 0x3c4e5fff  WebKit armv7  <2b33136aa86e383a83d32908bddc9667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3c4e6000 - 0x3c4e6fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <85e7546accc23ae1a973da4758512b7f> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x3c4e7000 - 0x3c514fff  MobileAsset armv7  <7ef1c10c0c493ad4b0073de317f2448d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x3c549000 - 0x3c7fefff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <dd6f3958c3d536d6be90836682d2ffee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
```

Comment: Run `atos -arch armv7 -o AppName 0x000791e4` or `atos -arch armv7 -o AppName 0x00079248` for getting the class method and line information of the relevant steps. You want to get that information on your own implementation and not on the OS's implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode can symbolicate crash logs of this kind for you. I don't think the latest Xcode allows dragging into Device Logs (doesn't work for me anyway), but you **can** put the file in ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/whatever-you-want/whatever-filename.crash and then open Organizer in Xcode. The crash log should be visible in Device Logs (the top one, not one of the device ones) and should symbolicate automagically.

I wrote a script for this which I pasted in a separate question: [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports/14242212#14242212) (I mention QuincyKit, but any crash log in the format you described above will work just fine).

Edit: from Kerni's comment, I noted that in order to drag&drop into Xcode Organizer, you need to (at least) 1) name the file properly (it requires the extension ".crash"), and 2) remove odd characters as Kerni explains in comment here. The QK client/server code can be patched to do this. See answer linked above.

Comment: You can drag them, if the `Incident Identifier` and `CrashReporter Key`have no special chars like `[` which lots of PLCrashReporter based crash reports do have. Remove those chars from the report and it let you drag them.

Comment: I tried and it didn't let me. Then I tried renaming the file (crash) to have the extension crash, i.e. "crash.crash" and THAT worked! Why the heck are the PLCR/QK devs doing this stuff...? -_-

Comment: I am the developer of QuincyKit. We are doing nothing with this stuff. The format is not publicly well defined so it is mostly unknown what to add in there, that is why PLCrashReporter doesn't fill in the values. Only recent changes in Xcode made it not accept the crash reports. On another note, your published crash file is NOT generated by PLCrashReporter/QuincyKit but is generated by iOS itself. PLCrashReporter does not format the `Last Exception Backtrace` the way you posted it. I would appreciate if you "soften" your language. Thank you.

Comment: Kerni: No offense meant, at all, but this stuff IS done by QuincyKit/PLCR. In fact, I just now came back here to post details on how to patch the stuff server- and client-side to get the two issues fixed. About to edit post now.

Comment: I see what you mean now. The specific crash report by the user here is not a QK/PLCR report. I agree with that, and my answer is borderline off topic. The reason I'm keeping it here is because it's generally about getting crash logs into Xcode and symbolicated, and my experience is mostly limited to QK/PLCR as that's what I use (hence the separate question link).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this answer: [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028)

Beside calling `atos` with the addresses of your own app, you also have to calculate the correct address first, since `0x000791e4` is the address at runtime which varies due to [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR). And since your dSYM only knows the address layout at build time, you need to make the calculations mentioned in the above answer first.

Besides that, the important information for that crash is in the `Last Exception Backtrace` part. Easiest way to get this symbolicated is to drag the crash report into the Xcode organizer `Device Logs` section. That will transform the `Last Exception Backtrace` part to a proper stack trace. If that doesn't work, search for the addresses that are in the range of your app and symbolicate these manually. The range of your app is also shown in the first line of the crash report below `Binary Images`.