# symbolicatecrash atos - getting number instead of method name

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, symbolicatecrash

I am unable to "Re-Symbolicate" using Xcode 6 with a crash log that a user sent me.  So I've tried to use `atos` and `symbolicatecrash` in order to manually convert hexadecimals adresses into method names in the stack trace.

I am using the right binary in order to do so but nor Xcode, nor `symbolicatecrash` are working. Here is an excerpt of the crash log:

```
Thread 12 Crashed:
0   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3b24de80 0x3b224000 + 171648
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3b24caac sqlite3_step + 404
2   AppSupport                      0x34187a26 CPSqliteStatementSendResults + 42
3   AppSupport                      0x3418bc22 CPRecordStoreProcessRecordStatementWithPropertyIndices + 138
4   AppSupport                      0x3418be9c CPRecordStoreProcessQueryWithBindBlock + 72
5   AppSupport                      0x3418bf1a CPRecordStoreCopyAllInstancesOfClassWhereWithBindBlock + 94
6   AddressBook                     0x2fd91216 ABCCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering + 242
7   bobler                          0x000c8778 0xba000 + 59256
8   bobler                          0x001bf0bc 0xba000 + 1069244
9   bobler                          0x000c8702 0xba000 + 59138
10  AddressBook                     0x2fdd36a4 __37-[ABTCC accessRequestWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 24
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b46a830 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b47d91c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 220
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3b47db1c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5acbd0 _pthread_wqthread + 296
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5aca94 start_wqthread + 4
```

Using atos I get those results:

```
0x000c8778 (in bobler) + 684
0x001bf0bc (in bobler)
0x000c8702 (in bobler) + 566
```

Anybody knows why I get numbers instead of method names?

ps: I'm sure that I'm using the same binary as the one on the crash log...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: This method did not work. Thanks

Comment: Check with `dwarfdump --uuid YourApp.app.dSYM` for the UUID of the dSYM and compare it with the UUID shown in the binary images section of the crash report. Provide the full crash report and dSYM as a zip somewhere and I can do a quick check.