# App is crashing only on device and cannot sybolicate the crash log.

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Below is my crash log but It seems I cannot find the exact point of crash using the crash log. I cannot reproduce the crash when I debug using the device but it crash If I install ipa. This does not happen often but randomly it crashes.

```
{"bundleID":"com.ihis.stg.aip","app_name":"aip_stg","bug_type":"109","name":"aip_stg","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)","version":"1.0.5 (1.0.1)"}
Incident Identifier: 70F600E1-127F-49D6-B673-BED90BE7FBF5
CrashReporter Key:   41bf250659ed0ca949c39f1f2a68a65f21285e0c
Hardware Model:      iPad4,2
Process:             aip_stg [402]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/01D2CF88-7532-4D56-A6B1-1F68D5077C40/aip_stg.app/aip_stg
Identifier:          com.ihis.stg.aip
Version:             1.0.5 (1.0.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-17 12:04:12.387 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  11

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x182647100 0x18f0241fc 0x182647040 0x1831a188c 0x1830f1df4 0x1830f1924 0x1830da544 0x1825591dc 0x1825590a8 0x1832a1118 0x1832a1274 0x1001252b4 0x10012874c 0x183103a84 0x1830f0a20 0x1831b2a38 0x18f5fbfd4 0x18f601654 0x18f5fbfd4 0x18f6032b8 0x18f6034fc 0x18f7916bc 0x18f79154c)

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9ca0 0x18f6f8000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182606d20 0x18253c000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182604f14 0x18253c000 + 823060
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182545dcc 0x18253c000 + 40396
4   GraphicsServices                0x00000001881e5c08 0x1881d8000 + 56328
5   UIKit                           0x0000000185676fc0 0x1855fc000 + 503744
6   aip_stg                         0x0000000100138288 0x1000a8000 + 590472
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018f617a9c 0x18f614000 + 15004

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9aa8 0x18f6f8000 + 6824
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f5fd998 0x18f5f8000 + 22936

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9ca0 0x18f6f8000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182606d20 0x18253c000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182604eb0 0x18253c000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182545dcc 0x18253c000 + 40396
4   Foundation                      0x000000018313a424 0x1830d0000 + 435236
5   Foundation                      0x00000001831c8408 0x1830d0000 + 1016840
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9ca0 0x18f6f8000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182606d20 0x18253c000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182604eb0 0x18253c000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182545dcc 0x18253c000 + 40396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018259b454 0x18253c000 + 390228
5   CoreMotion                      0x0000000182cfe538 0x182cc0000 + 255288
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9ca0 0x18f6f8000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182606d20 0x18253c000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182604eb0 0x18253c000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182545dcc 0x18253c000 + 40396
4   WebCore                         0x000000018c1333b8 0x18c034000 + 1045432
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f712394 0x18f6f8000 + 107412
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018382e470 0x183814000 + 107632
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183829f48 0x183814000 + 89928
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f712394 0x18f6f8000 + 107412
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183a56514 0x183814000 + 2368788
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183a565a8 0x183814000 + 2368936
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183829f48 0x183814000 + 89928
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 7 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9ca0 0x18f6f8000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182606d20 0x18253c000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182604eb0 0x18253c000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182545dcc 0x18253c000 + 40396
4   WebCore                         0x000000018c18d6a0 0x18c034000 + 1414816
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000183829f48 0x183814000 + 89928
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 8 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f6f9ca0 0x18f6f8000 + 7328
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182606d20 0x18253c000 + 830752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182604eb0 0x18253c000 + 822960
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182545dcc 0x18253c000 + 40396
4   Foundation                      0x00000001830e12c0 0x1830d0000 + 70336
5   Foundation                      0x000000018313ed74 0x1830d0000 + 454004
6   aip_stg                         0x00000001000b5c00 0x1000a8000 + 56320
7   Foundation                      0x00000001831c8408 0x1830d0000 + 1016840
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f71276c 0x18f6f8000 + 108396
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793e18 0x18f790000 + 15896
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f793d70 0x18f790000 + 15728
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791550 0x18f790000 + 5456

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f712394 0x18f6f8000 + 107412
1   Foundation                      0x00000001831af8e0 0x1830d0000 + 915680
2   Foundation                      0x0000000183103a80 0x1830d0000 + 211584
3   Foundation                      0x00000001830f0a1c 0x1830d0000 + 133660
4   Foundation                      0x00000001831b2a34 0x1830d0000 + 928308
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f5fbfd0 0x18f5f8000 + 16336
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f6024a4 0x18f5f8000 + 42148
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f5fe4bc 0x18f5f8000 + 25788
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f6030f0 0x18f5f8000 + 45296
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f6034f8 0x18f5f8000 + 46328
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f7916b8 0x18f790000 + 5816
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791548 0x18f790000 + 5448

Thread 11 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f71258c 0x18f6f8000 + 107916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018f6a6804 0x18f644000 + 403460
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e8cc990 0x18e8cc000 + 2448
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e8e9c28 0x18e8cc000 + 121896
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f0244d0 0x18f01c000 + 34000
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e8e7164 0x18e8cc000 + 110948
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018e8e71d4 0x18e8cc000 + 111060
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018f024428 0x18f01c000 + 33832
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f5fbfe4 0x18f5f8000 + 16356
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f601650 0x18f5f8000 + 38480
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f5fbfd0 0x18f5f8000 + 16336
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f6032b4 0x18f5f8000 + 45748
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018f6034f8 0x18f5f8000 + 46328
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f7916b8 0x18f790000 + 5816
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791548 0x18f790000 + 5448

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018f712e74 0x18f6f8000 + 110196
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018f791548 0x18f790000 + 5448
```

This is what I am getting out of the crash log

```
xcrun atos -arch armv7 -o 'aip_stg.app'/'aip_stg' 0x00000001000b5c00 0x1000a8000 + 56320
0x00000001000b5c00
0x1000a8000
+
___lldb_unnamed_function1934$$aip_stg (in aip_stg) + 396
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Use something like Crashlytics to find these types of crashes.