# iOS : Fail to symbolicate crash logs with atos

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, crash, symbolicate

I tried to symbolicate crash logs sent by Apple for one of my app.

I have three files .crash sent by Apple, if I take one of them, I've something like this :

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194bf2964 __kill + 8
1   MyApp                       0x000000010010d514 0x10007c000 + 595220
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000194c88958 _sigtramp + 64
```

So I think the problem is on the line "1" at the adress 0x10007c000 ?

I followed the solution posted here : [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) but when I do :

```
atos -arch armv7 -o 'APPNAME.app'/'APPNAME' 0x10007c000
```

I just have "0x10007c000" in answer....

What I need to do ? I don't understand.... And I found nothing from Apple Doc (to use atos to symbolicate)...

Thanks,

Comment: You didn't use google did you?  [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

Comment: Yes I saw it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html, but why It doesn't work with atos ? I want to understand how does it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected)