# Understanding demystified crash log iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, symbolicatecrash

I am trying to understand the crash log of crash issue which occurs while opening application. When user opens application it immediately crashes.

Following are the lines from crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3039528c 0x30381000 + 82572
1   myApp                           0x003bdd24 0x95000 + 3312932
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x304100a0 0x3040c000 + 16544
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30415c92 0x30412000 + 15506
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x30334934 0x302eb000 + 301364
5   myApp                           0x0017c7a4 0x95000 + 948132
6   myApp                           0x0017c490 0x95000 + 947344
7   myApp                           0x000ed8e8 0x95000 + 362728
8   myApp                           0x000ed010 0x95000 + 360464
9   myApp                           0x0017b842 0x95000 + 944194
10  UIKit                           0x2536fee0 0x252f6000 + 499424
```

After symbolicating Thread 0 and frame 1 related to myApp it looks like this:

```
__39+[CLSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]_block_invoke (in myApp) + 24
```

After symbolicating Thread 0 and frame 5 related to myApp it looks like this:

```
-[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] (in iPegs) (AppDelegate.m:448)
```

From first result `[CLSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` I didn't understand anything that can cause the crash in myApp and where to locate that code.

From second result `[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:]` The line 448 contains following code:

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"Import Document" withParameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Import Document",@"category",@"Import",@"action",@"open",@"label", nil] timed:YES];
```

The function handleOpenURL is as below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url])
    {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:COMMNAD_EXPORT_DROPBOX object:nil userInfo:nil];
        }
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([[ipegsClient shareInstance]getLoginUser]!=nil)
        {
            id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

            [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"Import Document"     // Event category (required)
                                                                  action:@"Import"  // Event action (required)
                                                                   label:@"open"          // Event label
                                                                   value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] build]];
            [Flurry logEvent:@"Import Document" withParameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Import Document",@"category",@"Import",@"action",@"open",@"label", nil] timed:YES];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:COMMAND_IMPORT_FILE_DOCUMENT object:url];


            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alr = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"myApp" message:@"Please login to import" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alr show];

            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }

    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

So could you please help me understanding this?

Comment: Is it happening while testing on simulator or this crash log is from some ones device to whom you have given the app to test. or it is from Apple?

Comment: This log is from one of our customer's iPad device.

Comment: Do check the version and model of customer's iPad? I am also facing this issue with my customers. As soon as they open the app it crashes. i tested it at my end but no crash.

Comment: iPad 2 and iOS 8.2, have you used crashlytics or flurry in your project for error reporting?

Comment: No I haven't used it

Comment: Maybe the way you symbolicated those frames returned wrong results?

Comment: The way I have used is answer given by @Chris on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028 post below your answer.