# atos won't symbolicate my address

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have received a crash report in just mail that isn't symbolicated. I have tried all previous posted solutions provided related to this bug but none of them worked for me.

Example:

> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1827ac22c 0x1944800e4 0x1827abbe0 0x100281224 0x1836adf9c 0x182763f8c 0x182763230 0x1827612e0 0x18268cf74 0x18c0e76fc 0x18728ed94 0x10001f2b0 0x194b2aa08)

I have `.app` and `.dSYM` files with me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What command line are you using with `atos`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Getting the same address back to me. Example : atos -o xyz.app/xyz -arch armv7 0x1827ac22c ... Result : 0x1827ac22c

Comment: Thanks @kerni for help . I don't have .crash file. I have only stack trace in mail . Your solution need .crash file for operations :-                           symbol address = slide + stack address - load address.

Comment: Without the start memory address of your binary on the crashing device at crash time you will not be able to symbolicate this. There is no way.

Comment: I have only stack trace populating in mail after app crashed using ASL.

Comment: This is not enough to get the symbols, as I already mentioned.