# Log callstack on remote server when error appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When an error appears on the user's device, the app logs the error description **and the callstack** on a remote server :

```
// Build the error string
NSString *error = [@"some error happened\n" stringByAppendingString:[NSThread callStackSymbols]];

// Log the error
NSLog(@"%@", error);

// Set up the web service address with param containing the error string
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:"https://myServer.com/myLoggerWebService?_error=error"];

// Send request to the server
id response = [NSString stringWithContentOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

- So when I look at the **logs in XCode**, I get a classic callstack containing all methods (with their understandable name) called before the error occured :

  ```
  0   MyAppName                           0x00000001014a1b3b -[GlobalFunctions prepareQuery:withStatement:] + 315
  1   MyAppName                           0x00000001014a3b7e -[GlobalFunctions insertIntoWithQuery:] + 78
  2   MyAppName                           0x00000001014a3ab9 -[GlobalFunctions insertInto:fields:values:] + 1417
  3   MyAppName                           0x0000000101488f67 -[Evenement save] + 3287
  4   MyAppName                           0x00000001014055c1 -[SyncElement saveOrUpdateWithPK:tableName:] + 241
  5   MyAppName                           0x0000000101485073 +[Evenement syncDownload:] + 1251
  6   MyAppName                           0x0000000101403228 +[SyncElement sync:] + 40
  7   MyAppName                           0x000000010141150b __61+[Sync syncClassesWithIndex:check:syncType:doBlockOnSuccess:]_block_invoke + 123
  8   MyAppName                           0x00000001014e8af8 __77+[MBProgressHUD(utils) initWithText:detailTxt:doBlock:onFinish:hideOnFinish:]_block_invoke + 56
  9   MyAppName                           0x000000010152bf88 __40+[BlockHelper doBlock:onQueue:onFinish:]_block_invoke + 56
  10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106ddde5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
  11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106dfe49b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
  12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106de6bef _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1829
  13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106de64c5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
  14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010712f4f2 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
  15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010712d375 start_wqthread + 13
  ```
- But when I look at the **logs on the remote server**, I get this useless callstack, *without the method names* :

  ```
  0   MyAppName                           0x00000001001612bc MyAppName + 479932
  1   MyAppName                           0x0000000100162e28 MyAppName + 486952
  2   MyAppName                           0x0000000100162b7c MyAppName + 486268
  3   MyAppName                           0x000000010015a854 MyAppName + 452692
  4   MyAppName                           0x000000010015a4dc MyAppName + 451804
  5   MyAppName                           0x000000010015a3cc MyAppName + 451532
  6   MyAppName                           0x000000010015a2cc MyAppName + 451276
  7   MyAppName                           0x0000000100103a40 MyAppName + 96832
  8   MyAppName                           0x000000010010ceb8 MyAppName + 134840
  9   MyAppName                           0x0000000100103d88 MyAppName + 97672
  10  MyAppName                           0x00000001001b395c MyAppName + 817500
  11  MyAppName                           0x00000001001b30dc MyAppName + 815324
  12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001952e1994 <redacted> + 24
  13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001952e1954 <redacted> + 16
  14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001952ec0a4 <redacted> + 1448
  15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001952e4a5c <redacted> + 132
  16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001952ee318 <redacted> + 720
  17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001952efc4c <redacted> + 108
  18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001954c121c _pthread_wqthread + 816
  19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001954c0ee0 start_wqthread + 4
  ```

Does someone know why ? If so, is there a way to log the readable callstack (i.e. the first one) on the remote server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to manually symbolicate each line of the stacktrace using [`atos`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/atos.1.html). This thread helped me : [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13574933/2791407)

Here's some documentation on symbolication and crash logs :

- [Guide : Analyzing Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html)
- [Technical Note : Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)