# App is rejected - Crashes on launch (iOS)

Tags: ios, crash, app-store

Tried to submit to app store but was rejected due to  crashed during launch. I have tried different methods to duplicate the crash but am unsuccessful. This is the crash report from Apple:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bdgx9gqpe6t4th/crash.rtf?dl=0

Thanks in advance for taking the time to review this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to change this crash report to symbolicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028

Answer (score 0):

Which iOS you are checking to generate the crash.Because it is crashed in 9.1.
So I recommend you to check your code with 9.1 ios or upper version.

Comment: Yes. I have checked with different iOS', front 6.2 to 9.1. It works fine and doesn't crash

Answer (score 0):

For Me the Problem is same

try this

But i solved my  problem like this

1.Run your app device.

2.Run your app on simulator

3.Check the App Review Information.

a)Demo Account

The user name and password for a full-access account for your app. This account is used during the review process and must not expire. Include details for additional accounts in the Notes field.