# ios debug crash log

Tags: ios, crash-log

My crash log looks like:

> Thread 0 Crashed: 
>   0 Odjezdy MHD  0x000000010008faac 0x100078000 + 96940 
>   1   Odjezdy MHD  0x000000010008e4e8 0x100078000 + 91368 
>   2   Odjezdy MHD  0x000000010008e534 0x100078000 + 91444 
>   3   UIKit        0x0000000186e18b40 -[UIViewControllerloadViewIfRequired] + 996

When i put it in the atos, it gives mi this:

> terminal$ atos -arch arm64 -o Odjezdy\ MHD.app/Odjezdy\ MHD 0x100078000 0x000000010008faac 
>   -[GMSCoordinateBounds(GoogleMaps) rectangle] (in Odjezdy MHD) + 144
>   -[GMSx_QTMCollectionViewController collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] (in Odjezdy MHD) + 220

Does anyone knows where can I find these lines of codes in my project? Or any idea where it could be some bug?? How can I can fix this bug?? :/ Thx a lot for any advice :)

Comment: You can not use `atos` with the addresses given in the stack trace. You also have to provide the app binary load address. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028

Comment: It looks so complicated :/ is something easier to get the method and lines of the crash from stack trace?? :/

Comment: No there is no easier way.