# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) crash report from Apple Review Team

Tags: ios, swift, logging, crash

I got this crash report from Apple Review Team, they said that the app crashed at lunch. I have symbolicate the crash log, double check the app version and the dSYM, but the first two lines after the Crash were not Symbolicated (Symbolicated crash at the end).

I haven't been able to reproduce the error by myself and this app has been tested by a lot of people and is currently been use by Beta testers, and non of them has reported this or any other crash. The same version of this app is approved on TestFlight but rejected for the Apple Store.

Here is the symbolicated log if some of you guys can give me some insight.

Thanks in advance

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001000e446c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
18.764194    CFNetwork                  0x000000018117fe7c TCP Conn 0x13ef3aed0 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
18.765782    CFNetwork                  0x00000001811813a8 TCP Conn 0x13ef3aed0 event 1. err: 0
19.628068    CFNetwork                  0x0000000181181480 TCP Conn 0x13ef3aed0 started
19.631343    CFNetwork                  0x00000001811dbe5c Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
19.631343    CFNetwork                  0x00000001811dbe28 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
19.631343    CFNetwork                  0x000000018122de50 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
24.382802    CFNetwork                  0x00000001810dd8e0 TCP Conn 0x13ee3e6c0 SSL Handshake DONE
24.428562    CFNetwork                  0x00000001810dd7f0 TCP Conn 0x13ee3e6c0 starting SSL negotiation
24.428880    CFNetwork                  0x000000018117fe7c TCP Conn 0x13ee3e6c0 complete. fd: 5, err: 0
24.429089    CFNetwork                  0x00000001811813a8 TCP Conn 0x13ee3e6c0 event 1. err: 0
24.459404    CFNetwork                  0x0000000181181480 TCP Conn 0x13ee3e6c0 started



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   mrquick                         0x00000001000e446c 0x100070000 + 476268
1   mrquick                         0x00000001000e2504 0x100070000 + 468228
2   UIKit                           0x0000000185c50c40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
3   UIKit                           0x0000000185c690d0 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 132
4   UIKit                           0x0000000185e03e5c -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1052
5   UIKit                           0x0000000185d0fe40 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
6   UIKit                           0x0000000185d0fb1c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
7   UIKit                           0x0000000185d0fa84 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
8   UIKit                           0x0000000185c4c1e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
9   QuartzCore                      0x00000001835de98c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
10  QuartzCore                      0x00000001835d95c8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
11  QuartzCore                      0x00000001835d9488 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
12  QuartzCore                      0x00000001835d8ab8 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001835d8818 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001835d1ddc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ab0728 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180aae4cc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180aae8fc __CFRunLoopRun + 928
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001809d8c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
19  GraphicsServices                0x00000001822c0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
20  UIKit                           0x0000000185cba088 UIApplicationMain + 204
21  mrquick                         0x00000001000ec5c4 0x100070000 + 509380
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001805768b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180694b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018075d530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018075d020 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: This crash report is not fully symbolicated, your apps frames are missing. Please fix that and you'll see where in your code the problem is. Make sure the UUID of the app binary in the crash report is identical to the dSYM UUID.

Comment: Hi @Kerni thanks, I don't know if I am doing something wrong, but I have follow this link **https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1765/_index.html** to make sure the UUIDs matches as you told me but, neither the version I upload or any other seems to match the crash UUID. So I try to run this command to try to symbolicate the lines that were not symbolicated: _**atos -o 12/mrquick.app/mrquick -arch armv7 -l 0x100070000 0x00000001000ec5c4**_ but the line I got doen't seems to have anything wrong, is that command valid?

Answer (score 0):

for the record I was able to find the crash and solve it, my App has been approved and is ready for sale!

In my case the crash was happening because I didn't take care of some functions when the user don't accept the App Location permissions, it crashes when trying to do a reverse geocoding.

For those having similar issues here I leave you some links that can help you resolve you Crash issue, and symbolicate the crash log.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1765/_index.html
- https://coderwall.com/p/ezdcmg/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-log-without-the-original-dsym-file
- [iOS crash reports: atos not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected/13576028#13576028)

Saludos