# IOS symbolication formula

Tags: ios, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, dwarf, symbolicate

1. I have read in various sites that while manually `symbolicating` an `ios Crash report`, we can get the symbol address using:

> symbol address = slide address + stack address - load address

But how do we get this?

These are the sites which mentions the above formula:

https://www.apteligent.com/developer-resources/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-report/#
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/13576028/5842876

2. Is there any way to symbolicate an crash in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, take a look at a typical unsymbolicated iOS crash. You'll find the following

- A load address
- Architecture
- Each frame will have an address associated with it

you can get the symbolicated frame using ATOS on mac:

`atos [-o <binary-image-file>] [-p <pid> | <partial-executable-name>] [-arch architecture]
          [-l <load-address>] [-s <slide>] [-printHeader] [-v] [-D] [-f <address-input-file>]
          [<address> ...]`

For the second question: Facebook provides an opensource replacement for ATOS called ATOSL you can find it [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/atosl) however it's not maintained and not as reliable as the native solution