# MetricKit MXDiagnostic symbolication

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode12, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I am trying to implement MetricKit so later I could analyze `MXCrashDiagnostic` and `MXHangDiagnostic` reports. However when I am triggering a test crash, and then doing `Debug->Simulate MetricKit Payloads` I always receive absolutely same result in `dictionaryRepresentation()`.
Here is an example of what I get for MXCrashDiagnostic:

```
[[AnyHashable("diagnosticMetaData"): {
    appBuildVersion = 2;
    appVersion = "1.0";
    deviceType = "iPhone10,6";
    exceptionCode = 0;
    exceptionType = 1;
    osVersion = "iPhone OS 14.0.1 (18A393)";
    platformArchitecture = arm64;
    regionFormat = CA;
    signal = 11;
    terminationReason = "Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb";
    virtualMemoryRegionInfo = "0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4000000000 REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL UNUSED SPACE AT START ---> __TEXT                 0000000000000000-0000000000000000 [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...pp/Test";
}, AnyHashable("callStackTree"): {
    callStackPerThread = 1;
    callStacks =     (
                {
            callStackRootFrames =             (
                                {
                    address = 74565;
                    binaryName = testBinaryName;
                    binaryUUID = "A36D6CF4-CBE8-4FB9-9DC4-C7EE8C6431CC";
                    offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment = 123;
                    sampleCount = 20;
                }
            );
            threadAttributed = 1;
        }
    );
}, AnyHashable("version"): 1.0.0]]
```

For `cpuExceptionDiagnostics` and `hangDiagnostics` the value for `callStackTree` is always the same.

I tried to symbolicate the the data, by executing commands:

```
1. cd /Path/To/Archive/myApp.xcarchive/dSYMs/myApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/
2. atos -arch arm64 -o myApp 0x00074565
```

But always get the same result:

```
atos[79918]: respawning is disabled (because DYLD_ROOT_PATH or DT_NO_RESPAWN is set), but the analysis process does not match the SDK variant of the target process 0.
Analysis of malloc zones may fail.
0x00074565 (in myApp)
```

I have found nothing online about the warning nor any of the params in xcode
I tried to follow [this](https://ask.xiaolee.net/questions/1014427)  and [this](http://iosbrain.com/blog/2018/02/14/debugging-symbolicating-crash-reports-manually-stack-trace-backtrace/) guides on the symbolication process, some answers were also provided to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574933/ios-crash-reports-atos-not-working-as-expected), but it looks like I don't have the right data for symbolication, even though I did set up reports correctly.

I would appreciate if someone could let me know what am I missing and how to properly symbolicate these reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it will always provide the same array contains MXDiagnosticPayload when you trigger the simulate metricKit payloads in XCODE.

Comment: Thank you! Should’ve figured out myself

Answer (score 2):

**Debug->Simulate MetricKit Payloads** It is just a example. It can not be symbolicated by atos.

The only wray is to collecting the payloads from users.

Answer (score 1):

There's a helpful thread on symbolicating MetricKit crash reports on Apple Developer Forums here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/681967

In short, for each call stack frame that you have a dSYM for (likely just your app), get the `offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment` and convert it from decimal to hex. Then invoke `atos` like this:

```
atos -arch arm64 -o <path to dSYM> 0x1 <offset in hex>
```

Where `<offset in hex>` is the value from `offsetIntoBinaryTextSegment` converted to hex. I used `arm64` in the example under the assumption that this is an iOS app.

You should also verify that the `binaryUUID` value in each frame matches the UUID of the dSYM file you're giving to `atos`. You can get the UUID of a dSYM file like this with `dwarfdump`:

```
dwarfdump --uuid <path to dSYM>
```

I've implemented this in a python script here:
https://github.com/OliveTreeBible/MXSymbolicate